# Un-usual behaviour of list comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm trying to understand List-comprehensions in python , I came across this behaviour of list comprehension. when I do:
 `[print(y) for y in range(0,10)]` it gives response

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

I understand it prints 0 to 9, but I don't understand why it prints `None` .But when I do `o = [print(y) for y in range(0,10)]` it prints

`0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9`

This time without any `none`,I couldn't find any relevant stuff by searching, can someone please explain , Thanks

Comment: It doesn't. The `None` are printed from another place. Maybe you did `print([print(y) for y in range(0,10)])`?

Comment: Are you on a jupyter? Jupyter will print the returned object of the latest statement in the cell

Comment: no I'm using builtin python interpreter on Ubuntu @Chris

Comment: No I did what I asked in question @Guy

Comment: writing the first command in a file and executing the file would give you the second output (without the `None`s)

Comment: As for the `[None, ...]` output: simply observe the difference between typing `'foo'` and `a = 'foo'` in the interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type anything from the interpreter, it will echo whatever the function or expression returns, unless it is `None` (the default).

For example:

```
>>> 1+1
2
```

Similarly, the `print` function calls get executed while the expression is being built, but the list of `None`s is actually the result of the expression.

You probably want to do something with it, so either:

```
[y for y in range(0,10)]
```

Or:

```
mylist = [y for y in range(0,10)]
```

Makes more sense. The `print` function prints the value, but then returns `None` and the value it printed is lost.

Comment: To nitpick, in Python 3 `print` is no longer a statement but a function, which is what is used here.

Comment: In fact the `print` function call is still a statement. You're right though that `print` by itself is no longer a valid statement and needs to be called as a function, but you could tell I was aware due to what I'm saying on the final line. I don't think there's anything wrong or confusing about what I was saying.

Comment: True, any expression (including function call) is a statement, so my wording is not really correct. But not every statement will have a return value, but functions have. That is the main gist here, and why I think it is worthwhile to point out that `print` is a *function* and not only a statement. As I said, just a nitpick, the answer is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The `print` function returns `None`, and you put these `None`s into your list. The elements are what the function returns, not what is printed on the screen. The printing-on-the-screen part is a [side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) of the `print` function.

Since there are already plenty of other answers showing what you probably wanted to do, I will not reproduce them here.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are basically doing thing like this:

```
x = []
for y in range(0,10):
    x.append(print(y))

print(x)
```

You should try `[y for y in range(10)]` instead.

Comment: The OP did not wanted to append the result to a list.

Comment: this is the list comprehensions to reduce the code  print([y for i in range(0,10)])

Answer (score 1):

It is because print function  prints output to the console, not to the list. This will give you your result:

```
[y for y in range(0,10)]
```

Or

```
list(map(lambda y: y, range(0,10)))
```